# Show array as written with rand inside

Tags: php

I have an array such as:

```
$var = array('hi','ho',rand(2,5));
```

What I would like to echo is the entire array, exactly as written.
Normally when you try a print_r, it shows as:

```
Array (
    [0] => hi
    [1] => ho
    [2] => 3
)
```

But I want:

```
Array (
    [0] => hi
    [1] => ho
    [2] => rand(2,5)
)
```

You can get this with `file_get_contents`, but is there any way to do so within the actual PHP file?

Comment: I don't think so. The rand() function is called always, and you are only able to get the value from that

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible because when array is created, random value is assigned to element with index 2 and you cannot check how this value was created.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible, since the rand is already evaluated as soon as you set the array to some variable.

A workaround would be the hold the expression as a string and then [eval](http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.eval.php) it when you need it. Like this:

```
$varStr = "array('hi','ho',rand(2,5))";
echo $varStr;

// when you actually need it
$var = eval($varStr);
```

However, this is almost never a good idea. Providing a use-case where you need this might help come up with a better solution.

Comment: That would work, but also require a bunch of recoding I don't want to have to do.
What I have is about 10,000 lines of code formatted as:
array('string',rand(2,5),rand(2,5));
The string is being changed, uploaded to a mysql database and then returned to me as an array like:
array('newstring',rand(2,5),rand(2,5));

But the rands need to stay intact. So I'm pretty much clueless on how to do it without recoding everything.

Comment: @user3286806 You will have to, anyways, in what kind of use case would you need such a printing: None. So whatever you try to do, do it differently. If you need the rand() to be still alive to give it some kind of other program, you will **have to** save it in a variable.